# Replacing issue in json

Tags: c#, .net, json, regex

I am trying to replace the string which i have

```
\\/Date(1430370000000+0530)\\/
```

to

```
\/Date(1430370000000+0530)\/
```

Code:

```
 string str = "\\/Date(1430370000000+0530)\\/";
 str = str.Replace(@"\","\\");           
 Console.WriteLine(str);
```

[See here the code running environment, click here](http://rextester.com/XRYHVO38997)

Output i am getting above is this :

```
\/Date(1430370000000+0530)\/
```

But while we pass the value in JSON property.

The value automatically converts to below value

```
/Date(1430370000000+0530)\\/
```

But I am expecting the same value which I got earlier

```
\/Date(1430370000000+0530)\/
```

Comment: You're replacing a backslash with a backslash... what do you expect that to do?

Comment: i m expecting /Date(1430370000000+0530)\\/

Comment: I've changed all your quoted pieces (where backslashes were being unescaped by markdown) into code pieces where there won't be any escaping. My guess is that you haven't *actually* got any double backslashes at all - you're just seeing that in the debugger.

Comment: You don't want to do *any* string replacement operations in JSON. Parse the JSON.

Comment: Note that in your sample code, you only start with single backslashes as well - try printing out `str` *before* the replacement, and you'll see it's exactly the same. (Which makes sense, as you're replacing something with itself.) I'm 99% sure this is just a diagnostic issue - you're misinterpreting what the debugger is showing you.

Comment: The line `str = str.Replace(@"\","\\");` replaces one backslash with one backslash. Did you intend to use `str = str.Replace(@"\",@"\\");`?